# Laravel - my left join query is not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have this query

```
 $data=Post::join('category', 'questions.categoryid', '=', 'category.CategoryId')
         ->where('category.CategoryName','demo')
        ->join('comments', function ($join) {
                $join->on('posts.postId', '=', 'comments.postId')
                ->where('posts.postId', '!=', 'comments.linkId');
        }) ->get();
```

I have above query where I am retrieving all posts based on category name and joining table with comments.

Everything is working fine but following line is not working. I mean even if add this line still its retrieving all records and even I tried to `!=` to `<>` but it's not working

```
->where('posts.postId', '!=', 'comments.linkId');
```

Comment: Hope you know this isn't a left join.  Laravel's join is an inner join.

Answer (score 2):

You don't use WHERE clauses within a JOIN, you can extend the ON clause:

```
->join('comments', function ($join) {
      $join->on('posts.postId', '=', 'comments.postId')
           ->on('posts.postId', '!=', 'comments.linkId');
})
```

Which will equate to:

```
JOIN comments ON posts.postId = comments.postId AND posts.postId != comments.linkId
```

Comment: @devon.Thanks i have tried this one .if i add like this then i m getting only one record which has comments.linkId

Comment: @devon.even i changed to left join then it will retrive all

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're after here but it no longer sounds like a Laravel issue, perhaps you just aren't understanding what a left join and inner join do?  Perhaps you want to look into Eloquent relationships instead?

Comment: @devon.ya leftjoin will give first table record even if we dont find in second table.but inner join only matches the record which is in both the table